Filter with join where null is wildcard
I'm writing a query in SQL Server, and I have a task to filter first table:



c1
c2
c3
c4




40
161
425
702


40
161
719
791


45
161
719
791


45
700
719
791


47
700
719
791



With data from second table:



c1
c2
c3
c4




40
NULL
NULL
NULL


45
161
NULL
NULL



The issue is, data in second table have "wildcards" - if there's NULL in column, than it can be any integer. Long story short, filtered table should look something like this:



c1
c2
c3
c4




45
700
719
791


47
700
719
791



I can probably end up with way to filter that with loop, but it seems don't be optimised at all.
To further clarify - the second table has "mask rules" to apply to the first table. Mask rules are going from c1 to c4:

t2.c1 can't be NULL
others can, but if t2.c2 is NULL, then t2.c3 should be too (just as t2).


Yeah, or: t1.c1 = ISNULL(t2.c1, t1.c1) it won't be fast though, but no wildcard queries like this are

your expected data doesn't look correct though, shouldn't it be 40 and 45 rows?

I'm sorry, question was not clear enough. Second table have "rules", by which rows from the first table should be deleted

I did temporary result table, then iterate through all rows in second table to match rows from the first - and if not, put them in result table. Unfortunately, it's seems like terrible way to do so.

I'm sorry - I'll be more careful next time. Thank you for your time, Dale!

One possibility is to use NOT EXISTS and then check for your filter conditions replacing null with the value from table1 so it matches e.g.
select *
from t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from t2
    where t1.c1 = t2.c1
    and (t1.c2 = isnull(t2.c2, t1.c2))
    and (t1.c3 = isnull(t2.c3, t1.c3))
    and (t1.c4 = isnull(t2.c4, t1.c4))
);

Note: This assumes that c1 cannot be null.
Returns:



c1
c2
c3
c4




45
700
719
791


47
700
719
791



DBFiddle

Just use (t1.col2 = t2.col2 OR t2.col2 IS NULL) conditions
select *
from t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from t2
    where t1.c1 = t2.c1
    and (t1.c2 = t2.c2 or t2.c2 is null)
    and (t1.c3 = t2.c3 or t2.c3 is null)
    and (t1.c4 = t2.c4 or t2.c4 is null)
);

db<>fiddle

Does the explicit OR perform better than the ISNULL alternative?

Possibly, because in theory the server can use an Index Union, athough in practice I think it's unlikely. Mainly it's much clearer what's going on.
